# How to get Meta tag from URL in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, meta-tags, messagebox

We are developing chat base app. In which we want to show meta tag info like WhatsApp and Skype are showing.

[image]

This is the [URL](http://mashable.com/2017/06/27/foursquare-asia-tencent-samsung/?utm_cid=hp-r-1#vanGE2s_tkq0) which send in Skype.

Does anyone know third party library for this feature?

I have also try to get completed HTML page for URL and try to parse XML but in that also I am not able to get all info.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is read meta tag from any XML Parser, I would recommend using 
[https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup)

but first you have to read html for the link use SwiftSoup for that
https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup

I am not able to find actual code for it, hence cannot share that here

Answer (score -1):

For this you have to get html string from the particular site like below,

```
- (void)getHtml
{
    NSURLSession *session = NSURLSession.sharedSession;
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mashable.com/2017/06/27/foursquare-asia-tencent-samsung/?utm_cid=hp-r-1#vanGE2s_tkq0"]
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                NSLog(@"http string: %@", htmlString);
                                            }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Once you get html, you have to parse html and get your tags which you what to display.

Html parser you can use [HTMLKit](https://github.com/iabudiab/HTMLKit)